# Error crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

Tags: php, apache, google-cloud-platform, httpd

Tenía mi aplicación corriendo desde hace unos meses normalmente hasta ayer en la tarde.
Hoy en la mañana me arroja el sgte error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el warning dice: **crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.**
Mi aplicación estaba hecha con Codeigniter y desde hoy en la mañana no puedo hacer conexion a ella.

No se han realizado cambios al código de la App.
Se encuentra en una máquina virtual de Google Cloud con Apache instalado y phpMyAdmin hasta hace poco se le instaló un certificado ssl, sin embargo no tuvo problemas hasta hoy.

Al parecer no hay una razón clara para la causa según he investigado.

Es mi primer post en esta página lamento si es un poco vago o requiere más información, de ser así por favor indicarme que más información puedo entregar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Nota que un warning es distinto que un error. Tener warnings por deprecación es común, usualmente se introducen por actualizaciones de las dependencias y el mensaje suele ser suficientemente descriptivo para poder quitar el warning, aunque algunas veces el warning viene de alguna dependencia de una dependencia y en esos casos no hay mucho más que hacer que esperar que lo parchen. Deberías intentar hacer un RCA para ver que cosa origina dicho warning, sin embargo no debería causar problemas graves por un tiempo razonable.

Comment: El problema está en que ese warning en particular nada descriptivo y el sistema no ha sido actualizado. Este warning es el único mensaje que señala el sistema para no mostrar ninguno de los servicios de mi aplicación.

Comment: Nota que es probable que la request fallida que estás teniendo no tenga nada que ver con el warning de deprecación. Igual te recomiendo buscar ese mensaje de error en google a ver si te aparece algo interesante. Creo que la pregunta es muy amplia para que te podamos ayudar con la información que nos das.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este mismo error `Error crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated` corriendo una aplicación en Angular tan sólo me funcionó **borrar las cookies** del navegador (Chrome).

Mi error iba a compañado de un `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()`

Ósea un badRequest, que muchas veces puede darse por una Caché y Cookies del navegador corruptas.

En mi caso la misma aplicación corriendo en modo Launch Debug Chrome VSCode o en modo incógnito funcionaba correctamente, así que al final opté por borrar primero la caché (seguía fallando) luego las cookies (y se solucionó).

Otras cosas que probé anteriormente, siguiendo distintas soluciones proporcionadas por la comunidad y que en mi caso NO funcionaron.

- Reiniciar el ordenador.
- Reinstalar módulos del proyecto.
- Eliminar launch.json.
- Redefinir launch.json.
- Checkear que el Network del browser esté en modo `No throttling`
- Checkear que la URL que se intenta alcanzar es la correcta.
- Reiniciar las configuraciones de red.

Comment: De hecho, la solución a mi problema consistía en un conjunto de Cookies de Chrome y el pago del dominio del sitio. Una vez hecho esta limpieza el sitio continuó funcionando normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Soy nuevo en esto de angular y me acaba de pasar lo mismo con este mensaje de error el cual me mostraba en consola un archivo que mostraba un error en console.warn. Busque soluciones en varios sitios y blogs y nadie me lo proporciono. Lo que por ultimo realice fue reiniciar mi computadora y al entrar en el proyecto abierto VSCode y visualizar la pagina me arrojo temporalmente otro error que me dio la pista de volver a llamar el comando "ng serve" y esto me reestableció la pagina de Angular. Espero a alguien mas le sirva esto pues a mi me lo soluciono y es el primer día que trabajo con un proyecto de Angular.